# Strange behaviour of cwt at the end and the beginning in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, wavelet-transform

I have been experiencing with the continous wavelet transform (CWT) in matlab R2016a, and found something strange. When I do a CWT to a constructed signal, and plot the logarithm of the absolute value of the coefficients, the figure shows, that at the end, and the beginning there are very high frequencies, but if I do the CWT to a larger interval, and then limit that, then there are no such strange effects. Here are two pictures, which illustrate that:
[image: strange]
[image: not strange]
In the first one I do the CWT to the limited interval, but in the second I limit the plot after I did the CWT, here is my MWE:

```
Fs=160;
time=1/160:1/160:61;
data=sin(time);
figure;
cfrq=centfrq('morl');
minscl=cfrq*Fs/100;
maxscl=cfrq*Fs;
scales = minscl:maxscl;

cfs = cwt(data,scales,'morl');

colormap(jet);
pfreq = scal2frq(scales,'morl',1/Fs);
contourf(time,pfreq,log(abs(cfs)),'LineStyle','none');
axis tight;
grid on;
xlim([40 50]);
figure;
time=time(40*160:50*160);
data=data(40*160:50*160);

cfs = cwt(data,scales,'morl');

colormap(jet);
pfreq = scal2frq(scales,'morl',1/Fs);
contourf(time,pfreq,log(abs(cfs)),'LineStyle','none');
axis tight;
grid on;
```

Please help explain this strange effect, thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is related to the assumption of a periodic input signal when calculating an FFT (or CWT). In your example, the start and end value are completely different. So, if you repeat your signal periodically, you get a huge jump when going from the last sample to the first sample of the next repetition. This results in high amplitudes in your CWT image.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the problem is related to the assumption of a periodic input signal when calculating an FFT (or CWT). In your example, the start and end value are completely different. So, if you repeat your signal periodically, you get a huge jump when going from the last sample to the first sample of the next repetition. This results in high amplitudes in your CWT image.